# How do I upgrade java from 1.8 to 11

Tags: java, android, android-studio, plugins

I have an android app I am building using Android Studio.  All of a sudden I received a build.gradle warning: Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run.  You are currently using Java 1.8.

the problem I see refers to the second line in this code;

```
plugins {
id 'com.android.application'
id 'kotlin-android'
}
```

I am running Android Studio on a MacBook pro.
I have tried various fixes but most are for PC and since I am using a Mac they don't seem to help.

Does anyone have a solution.

Comment: Step 1: Install [sdkman!](https://sdkman.io/) Step 2: `sdk install java 11.0.16.1.fx-librca`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting -> BuildTool -> Gradle -> choose java 11 or download something as request